# Running a surround system on a 12V battery

Tags: 12v

*Hello all engineers. I've recently started a portable music box project.
For someone like me with very limited knowledge about electronics I got what seemed like a brilliant idea.
I've got several sound systems laying around. They're all functioning perfectly when connected to an electrical outlet in the wall.*

**Question:**
What is needed to run my surround sound system on a 12V battery?

**Specifications on the sound system**
The ones I'd like to try this project with are the "Logitech Surround Sound Speakers Z506". The back reads: INPUT 120-240V ~50/60Hz 800mA.

Looking forward to any answer - using a well functioning sound system with the build in amp in a new environment seems so much easier than me screwing up the electric impedance calculations.

**update:**
My question was answered, Thanks Chris and Michael. I'll not pursue the original idea, but do it properly instead. *Hat off*

Comment: what more than an inverter do you want?

Comment: If you are going through the original mains power supply, you need an inverter.  If you are hoping to bypass the original supply, you need detail not provided in your question.  Do note that there are lots of cheap packaged amplifiers intended for automotive applications which already run off 12v.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can find an [inverter that takes 12VDC and produces a fake 120VAC waveform](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01B3ZQG4O) that should get the idea off the ground. Such inverters are not 100% efficient however - expect something more like 65%.

If your sound system takes 120VAC at 0.8 amps that corresponds to a power draw at 96 watts. An inverter at 65% efficiency would require an input power of 96/0.65 = 147 watts of energy from the battery. A battery at 12V to supply that power would be delivering a current of 147/12 ~= 12 amps.

As you can see it would require a really decent sized battery to supply this level of power for any length of time. Assume that the battery was one that you discharge at 0.1C (where C is the amp-hour rating of the battery). That would require a battery with an amp-hour rating of 120AH.

[Amazon shows a 12V 120Ah](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LY76Y16) sealed lead acid battery at $230US. Such battery weighs almost 73 pounds. I will leave it to you to decide if that qualifies as "portable".